# Laravel 5.4 View injection from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I've just upgraded to Laravel 5.4 and everything's working correctly apart from a section injection.

So I create my view

```
$view = View::make('layouts.' . $content->template)->with($data);
```

I then pull the page HTML from SQL and do some manipulation.

I've been using the following which was fine in 5.3

```
$view->getFactory()->inject('final-content', $contentHtml);
```

I'll then render it with....

```
echo $view->with($data)->render();
```

However, since Laravel 5.4, the injected section content is being escaped. I can't see any way to avoid that.

Cheers in advance,

Comment: This is (sort of) in the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade#upgrade-5.4.0) You're going to have to put the content in the traditional way (pass it via a variable and use `{!! !!}`)

Comment: That was my fear, I've been working on that whilst waiting for a miracle answer! Thanks @apokryfos